# Get value from HTML form-card , to pass a HTML modal

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I am beginner.
if I click on **save** button the modal is open with two buttons 1. **cancel** 2. **ok**  and then **ok** can send a backend as checkbox is clicked or not. but not getting a checkbox is enable or disable
I want to send a  **NADIM_CONF_LOGGING_OPTIONS_ENABLE_STATE** , if I click on Okay

```html
<div class="form-card container">             
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Set Options</h4> 
              <!--  <div class="d-flex justify-space-between"> --> 
                        <input id='nadim_conf-logging-options-enable-hid' type='hidden' value='disabled' name='SYS_CFG_LOGGING_OPTIONS_ENABLE_STATE'> 
                        <input id='nadim_conf-logging-options' name='NADIM_CONF_LOGGING_OPTIONS_ENABLE_STATE' type='Checkbox' value='enabled' $$$sys_cfg_logging_options_enable$$$> 
                        <label class="radio-button-label" for="nadim-conf-logging-options"> logging suceessful
                        <label>
                            <svg class="info-icon" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 22 22" onclick="openModal()">
                                <path
                                    d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 16h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v3z" />
                            </svg>
                         </label>
                </div>                
                <div class="bottom-row"> 
                    <button class="btn" id='logging-options-save' type='submit' method='post'>Save</button> 
                </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    
    
    
    
            </div>
        <div id="confirmation-modal" class="modal">
            <form action="sys_config.htm" method="post">
                <div class="modal-content form-card container">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Warning</h4>
                        <div class="text-body">
                            Select Cancel to keep the setting unchanged and preserve your data. Otherwise, select OK to proceed
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-row">
                        <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn" id='wrg-logging-options-save' type="submit" method="post">Ok</button>
                        <input name='NADIM_CONF' type='hidden' value="NADIM_CONF_LOGGING_OPTIONS_SUBMIT">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```